# Rollback if one operation fails

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have not found a specific post here on how to rollback previous operation on sql server if one operation in a set of operations fails.

I have for instance one query to bring some data them I add a row with `context.saveChanges()`, then perhapes a second and a third insert are performed.

Ok, this last insert fails, so I want to get the db state to the state it was before the three inserts.

I am using EF4, and SQL Server 2008 R2 + Asp Net MVC 4 / C#.

Is transaction the only way to do it? 
As thoses operations has been saved one by one (programatically) and not in just one `context.saveChange()`, I am not sure how to perform the rollback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do "nested transactions" like this using TransactionScope.

Wrap your logic in

```
using (var transScope = new TransactionScope())
{

    //add something
    context.SaveChanges();

    //do something else
    context.SaveChanges();

    if (foo == bar) //check that it worked fine
    {
        transScope.Commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, do nothing. SaveChanges used a transaction already internally. It is atomic - either the changes are saved, or not.

Comment: As far as I understand the question the OP calls `SaveChanges` multiple times.